# Update in PostgreSQL performance relative to Select

Tags: postgresql

When I perform this simple Select query, the response is returned in 30ms.

```
select u.id, cv.id
from units u
left join volumes v on v.value = u.value
left join carrier_units cu on cu.id = u.mccus_inspection_id
left join carriers c on c.id = cu.carrier_id
left join carrier_volumes cv on cv.vehicle_id = v.id and cv.carrier_id = c.id
where u.carrier_vehicle_id is null
and cv.id is not null
and u.id = 115215784
and cv.date = cu.date
```

However, when I try and perform an Update using an identical pattern, it takes 120 seconds or more.

```
UPDATE units
SET carrier_vehicle_id = cv.id
from units u
left join volumes v on v.value = u.value
left join carrier_units cu on cu.id = u.mccus_inspection_id
left join carriers c on c.id = cu.carrier_id
left join carrier_volumes cv on cv.vehicle_id = v.id and cv.carrier_id = c.id
where u.carrier_vehicle_id is null
and cv.id is not null
and u.id = 115215784
and cv.date = cu.date
```

How do I improve the performance of the Update statement to be more in line with the Select query?

Comment: how large is the table and which index have you got on `carrier_vehicle_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `UPDATE` joins `units` with itself without a join condition. Your outer joins are really inner joins, so you should rewrite the `UPDATE` as

```
UPDATE units u
SET carrier_vehicle_id = cv.id
from volumes v
cross join carrier_units cu
join carriers c on c.id = cu.carrier_id
join carrier_volumes cv on cv.vehicle_id = v.id and cv.carrier_id = c.id
where v.value = u.value
and cu.id = u.mccus_inspection_id
and u.carrier_vehicle_id is null
and cv.id is not null
and u.id = 115215784
and cv.date = cu.date;
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the answer and the help!